# List index out of bound (8)

Tags: sql, oracle, importerror, toad, oracle11gr2

I want to import data from Excel file (.xlsx) to an Oracle DB table using Toad, but I get this error message. 
Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: Please show us your code so that we may help you.

Comment: Hi! I'm using the Import Table Data option under the 
Database / Import tab of TOAD

Comment: A list index out of bounds is a Toad bug and an error log with call stack is probably generated. There may be a workaround, but you're best off posting this to the Toad forum (toadworld.com) so that the dev team can A) fix the issue and B) suggest a workaround after identifying the cause.

Comment: Or, if you'd like you can post the contents of the log file (Toad.el or Toad.elf depending on version) here and I can take a look and forward it as needed. On the General page in options there is an "Application Data Directory" group box with a folder path. The error log file will be in that folder if one was generated.

Comment: save the xlsx as a csv file, then import using sqlldr (or Toad if you must)